# Yesod Architecture

Tags: model-view-controller, architecture, yesod

I'm really new to Yesod and in particular to Functional programming and software architecture.
I'm attending a course on software architecture and I have to explain Yesod architecture.
Here's what I understand:
Yesod implement the MVC pattern using Shakespeare as "View", Persistent as a "Model" and Yesod itself as a Controller. But I don't get where to collocate the Warp server. Can you tell me?

Furthermore, what is the Yesod architecture itself? I read "The Architecture of Open Source Applications" book but I don't really get if it uses a layered architecture or a component based architecture, I'm quite confident that it uses a component based architecture (correct me if I'm wrong) but I can't spot which are the component (can you tell me?).

Recap of doubts:
- Role of Web server in the MVC pattern
- Yesod architecture itself.
- Component/Layer of the yesod architecture.

Thank you all for your time.

Here is the piece of the book description about Yesod:

> The most basic feature of Yesod is routing. It features a declarative syntax and type-safe dispatch. Layered on top of this, Yesod provides many other features: streaming content generation, widgets, i18n, static files, forms and authentication. But the core feature added by Yesod is really routing.
>
> This layered approach makes it simpler for users to swap different components of the system. Some people are not interested in using Persistent. For them, nothing in the core system even mentions Persistent. Likewise, while they are commonly used features, not everyone needs authentication or static file serving.
>
> On the other hand, many users will want to integrate all of these features. And doing so, while enabling all the optimizations available in Yesod, is not always straightforward. To simplify the process, Yesod also provides a scaffolding tool that sets up a basic site with the most commonly used features.

And a link to the book [AOSABOOK](http://aosabook.org/en/yesod.html)

Comment: I tried to write a parts enumeration in the [Yesod wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yesod_(web_framework)) but check the [Yesod web and book](http://www.yesodweb.com/) for a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

It's of course MVC. It is stated on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yesod_%28web_framework%29). And also the file structure in Yesod are much similar to that of other MVC framework.

Answer (score 0):

I'm mainly a Rails developer, so my notion of MVC is arguably warped. But translating to Rails (if it helps anyone) I see the Yesod structure like this:

`Handler/` contains your controllers (relatedly, `config/routes` is your routes file), `templates/` are your views, and the add-on `Persistent` is your ORM for models.